# Issue pulling custom fields from DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

Hi stackoverflow community!

I'm working on creating some logic to dynamically update my template with different content for specific recipients. When I make a GET call to pull the custom fields I've added, I see this:

### GET Call

GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/custom_fields

### GET Request results

```
{
    "textCustomFields": [
        {
            "fieldId": "10351158661",
            "name": "templateUsageRestriction",
            "show": "false",
            "required": "false",
            "value": "allOptions"
        }
    ],
    "listCustomFields": []
}
```

Does anyone know what the "templateUsageRestriction" means/how to pull the actual fields?

Answer (score 0):

These are fields created by DocuSign when you use a template to create an envelope. Your code should ignore these.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get form data entered by signers, you'll want to use the [EnvelopesFormData::Get](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeFormData/get) method, or the [Recipients::List](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list) method with `include_tabs=true`.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind when I'm doing the update.

I am currently stuck on the step to pull all the custom fields. The only field that shows up is the one shown in the post question. The step after that is to populate the fields via a POST call before sending the template to the recipients.

Comment: Envelope Custom Fields are metadata embedded in the envelope, and you're currently not using any. If you want to get tags that are available in the Signing Session, use the Recipients::List method with `include_tabs` as documented above.